# Display parent child hierarchy in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have an Oracle table like below

```
EMPNO   EMPNAME     MANAGERID
1       EMP1    
2       EMP2          1
3       EMP3          2
```

By using above table, I want to display employee manager hierarchy like below,

```
EMPNO   EMPNAME     EMPHIERARCHY    (Contains EMP name and Manager Name(Managers Manager as well))
1       EMP1    
2       EMP2        EMP2,EMP1
3       EMP3        EMP3,EMP2,EMP1
```

Could anyone please guide me how to achieve this in Oracle?.

Comment: Search this site for `connect by` and `listagg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "standard" hierarchy you need this query:

```
select empno, empname, sys_connect_by_path(empname, '/') hierarchy
  from test connect by managerid = prior empno start with managerid is null
```

Output:

```
      EMPNO EMPNAME    HIERARCHY
----------- ---------- ----------------
          1 EMP1       /EMP1
          2 EMP2       /EMP1/EMP2
          3 EMP3       /EMP1/EMP2/EMP3
```

---

For hierarchy "inverted" this query worked:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52019/1)

```
select root1 empno, root2 empname, hierarchy from (
  select empno, empname, managerid, prior empname,
      sys_connect_by_path(empname, '/') hierarchy, connect_by_isleaf leaf,
      connect_by_root(empno) root1, connect_by_root(empname) root2
    from test connect by prior managerid = empno
  ) where leaf = 1
```

Output:

```
     EMPNO EMPNAME    HIERARCHY
---------- ---------- ----------------
         1 EMP1       /EMP1
         2 EMP2       /EMP2/EMP1
         3 EMP3       /EMP3/EMP2/EMP1
```

More about [hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns001.htm).

Comment: Thanks Stibbons for your help.